# ASP.NET Health Monitoring or ELMAH what to choose?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, elmah

net 4 in C# with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to choose an error logging solution for my Web Application.

I read some article [ELMAH](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs) and [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs) on the topic but I would like have your opinion and thoughts on which system you prefers in your a real world application and why.

Some point in which I'm interested:

```
- setup and configuration
- error reports
- performance
```

Comment: You may want to watch out promoting your product in your posts if it's unrelated to the question at hand.  IMHO it's walking the line of a spam flag.

Comment: Sorry Jim I do not understand but I'm not affiliated in any way with any products (and no links are posted on my post). Please let me know how I can improve my question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to offend.  Trying to figure out the bit about SmartAssembly.

Comment: SmartAssembly is offerring logging capabilities for error. But I never tried before and it is not com for free

Comment: Not much compares to elmah that is free, there are lots of better tools, but they all cost money.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET Health Monitoring is not a logging solution. According to [ASP.NET Health Monitoring overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx):

ASP.NET health monitoring enables you to do the following tasks:

- Monitor the performance of an application to make sure that it is healthy.
- Rapidly diagnose applications or systems that are failing.
- Appraise significant events during the life cycle of an application.
- Monitor live ASP.NET applications, individually or across a Web farm.
- Log events that do not necessarily relate to errors in an ASP.NET application.

The level of required configuration depends on what you need to accomplish. For several of my applications, all we need is:

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <rules>
    <add name="Application Lifetime Events On" eventName="Application Lifetime Events" 
         provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default"/>
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

This enables health monitoring and adds application lifetime events to those events collected by default. This way, we know when an application starts and stops, and why.

Note that we didn't have to touch any code to get this functionality.

Comment: I don't believe in logging, in general. When I have worked at places that required logging, i have often used the Logging Application Block from the Enterprise Library. It works well, is very flexible and extensible, and is very configurable, and there's a GUI-based tool for editing the configuration. I especially like the fact that the level of logging can be finely controlled, so I can configure it back to "no logging unless you have to".

Comment: ***IMHO*** Years after, I don't found any good patterns and practices using ***ASP.NET Health Monitoring***. Maybe looks as *obsolete*, or _Microsoft_ forget it. Neither gurus talk about it? anybody use it in real production environment? **Nick Craver** not use in stackoverflow neither **Scott Hanselman**, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I found set up and integration with ELMAH very very easy to do. If you use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) to install ELMAH, It would be a piece of cake like Scott Hanselman shows in [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays027) video.

You just need to do following on your package manager and thats it:-

install-package elmah

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of opinion (and requirements), but I'd choose ELMAH because it offers everything MS Health Monitoring offers, and then some. The biggest feature for me is the built in error viewer from ELMAH.

Answer (score 2):

I started using ELMAH ever since Scott Hanselman said it was the greatest thing since sliced bread, and I really do like it. As Esteban stated above, it monitors much more than MS Health Monitor, and is much more configurable.

You could also use come combination of log4Net or the Enterprise Library logging and Exception blocks, along with enabling HTTP errors in the registry, but really, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/